# How to listen to KAFKA topic which is configured chroot in broker in Java

Tags: apache-kafka, chroot

CHRoot is configured in Kafka broker, how to listen to the topic which is in /chroot

Comment: `chroot` can't be configured on a per-topic basis. When used, it is a part of broker's `zookeeper.connect` property.

Answer (score 1):

Clients haven't needed to communicate with Zookeeper since Kafka < 0.9, therefore chroot doesn't matter and `zookeeper.connect` should no longer be used.

Comment: 0.81 is an ancient version. New consumers should use `bootstrap.servers` config to connect to Kafka, see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs

Comment: @KarthiTamilveeran Please remove `081` from that link, or use the docs for the version of Kafka you are actually using

Comment: I agree that, for latest Kafka there is no need to give any chroot path as this goes to zookeeper alone, not KAFKA.

Comment: I am getting following exception when i connect to KAFKA 2.11-0.11.0.2 [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-1784] Coordinator discovery failed, refreshing metadata (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator) and then TImeout after someting

Comment: @Karthi You might want to post a new question with your code and configs, but you are also still using an old version of Kafka. I'm not sure I understand why you're asking about chroots if that's your error